# FInding Coefficient of Term in an Expansion

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics

I have the expression $(0.1x + 0.2x^2 + 0.3x^3 + 0.4x^4)^k$ and I'm attempting to figure out how to find the coefficient at $x^y$ for any $y$ and $k$. I understand that I can simply expand the expression, however as $k$ increases this becomes increasingly tedious to do by hand. I believe I need to use binomial/multinomial theorem but I do not understand how to use it in this situation, where each term of $x$ has a different coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

> “The patient says, "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." The doctor says,
> "Then don't do that!”
>
> ― Henny Youngman

If it's tedious to do it by hand, then don't do it by hand.  Use some appropriate software.  Here's how to do it in *Mathematica*:

```
Coefficient[x^k (1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3)^k/10^k /. k -> 13, x^y /. y -> 17]
(* 11843/5000000000000 *)
```

Note that $x^k (1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3)^k/10^k$ is equivalent to your $(0.1x+0.2x^2+0.3x^3+0.4x^4)^k$.

I understand the desire for an analytical form but I don't think it exists as [OEIS A329709](https://oeis.org/A329709) does not provide any analytic formulas for such a sequence.

What you can do is use a recursive approach.  Consider the main troublesome piece:  $(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3)^k$.  The coefficient of $x^i$ for a particular value of $k$ can be written as

$$T(k,i)=\sum_{j=\max(0,i-3(n-1))}^{\min(i,3)} T(1,j) T(k-1,i-j)$$

with $T(1,0)=1$, $T(1,1)=2$, $T(1,2)=3$, and $T(1,3)=4$.

Comment: I have used wolfram alpha to solve for a given $y$ and $k$, however what I'm interested in is how I could solve it analytically without expanding the expression by hand. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: No need to be sorry.  You were very clear.  But find the coefficients for $(1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3)^3$ (which are {1, 6, 21, 56, 111, 174, 219, 204, 144, 64}) in oeis.org (https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+6%2C+21%2C+56%2C+111%2C+174%2C+219%2C+204%2C+144%2C+64&language=english&go=Search) and you'll find a reference but no nice formula.  That many times means that no nice general formula exists for arbitrary integer values of $k$ and you'll simply need to write some code to get the coefficients for specific values of $k$.